# How to make unique_ptr work with Qt's QHash and QString?

Tags: c++, qt, unique-ptr, qstring, qhash

I am learning the intrincacies of unique_ptr.

I have a working example of a std::unordered_map that holds std:string and std::unique_ptr<std::string>.

But I can't make unique_ptr examples with Qt's QString and QHash work. They won't compile mentioning errors like *use of deleted function*.

How can I make the two last examples work?

#### *Edit 1*

In case this info is relevant, I am using *gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0*.

### Example 1 (working): unordered_map and string

#### unordered_map_string.h

```cpp
#ifndef UNORDERED_MAP_STRING_H
#define UNORDERED_MAP_STRING_H

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class UnorderedMapString
{
public:
    UnorderedMapString() {};

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> container;

    void addItem(std::string aKey, std::unique_ptr<std::string> aValue);

    void showItem(std::string aKey);
};

#endif // UNORDERED_MAP_STRING_H
```

#### unordered_map_string.cpp

```cpp
#include "unordered_map_string.h"

#include <iostream>

void UnorderedMapString::addItem(std::string aKey, std::unique_ptr<std::string> aValue)
{
    container[aKey] = std::move(aValue);
}

void UnorderedMapString::showItem(std::string aKey)
{
    std::string *aValue = container[aKey].get();
    std::cout << "Item '" << aKey << "': '" << *aValue << "'\n";
}
```

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "unordered_map_string.h"

#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UnorderedMapString testContainer;

    testContainer.addItem("key 1", std::make_unique<std::string>("one value"));
    testContainer.addItem("key 2", std::make_unique<std::string>("two value"));
    testContainer.addItem("key 3", std::make_unique<std::string>("three value"));

    testContainer.showItem("key 2");
    testContainer.showItem("key 3");
    testContainer.showItem("key 2");

    return 0;
}
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(unique_ptr_string LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(unique_ptr_string
  main.cpp
  unordered_map_string.h unordered_map_string.cpp
)
```

### Example 2 (not working): unordered_map and QString

#### unordered_map_qstring.h

```cpp
#ifndef UNORDERED_MAP_QSTRING_H
#define UNORDERED_MAP_QSTRING_H

#include <QString>

#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

class UnorderedMapQString
{
public:
    UnorderedMapQString() {};

    std::unordered_map<QString, std::unique_ptr<QString>> container;

    void addItem(QString aKey, std::unique_ptr<QString> aValue);

    void showItem(QString aKey);
};

#endif // UNORDERED_MAP_QSTRING_H
```

#### unordered_map_qstring.cpp

```cpp
#include "unordered_map_qstring.h"

#include <iostream>

void UnorderedMapQString::addItem(QString aKey, std::unique_ptr<QString> aValue)
{
    container[aKey] = std::move(aValue);
}

void UnorderedMapQString::showItem(QString aKey)
{
    QString *aValue = container[aKey].get();
    std::cout << "Item '" << aKey.toStdString() << "': '" << (*aValue).toStdString() << "'\n";
}
```

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "unordered_map_qstring.h"

#include <QString>

#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UnorderedMapQString testContainer;

    testContainer.addItem("key 1", std::make_unique<QString>("one value"));
    testContainer.addItem("key 2", std::make_unique<QString>("two value"));
    testContainer.addItem("key 3", std::make_unique<QString>("three value"));

    testContainer.showItem("key 2");
    testContainer.showItem("key 3");
    testContainer.showItem("key 2");

    return 0;
}
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(unique_ptr_qstring LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_executable(unique_ptr_qstring
  main.cpp
  unordered_map_qstring.h unordered_map_qstring.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(unique_ptr_qstring Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)
```

#### EDIT 2: compile errors for example 2

```
$ make
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/unique_ptr_qstring.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h: In constructor ‘UnorderedMapQString::UnorderedMapQString()’:
/home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:12:27: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map() [with _Key = QString; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<QString>; _Hash = std::hash<QString>; _Pred = std::equal_to<QString>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> > >]’
   12 |     UnorderedMapQString() {};
      |                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:47,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:141:7: note: ‘std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_map() [with _Key = QString; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<QString>; _Hash = std::hash<QString>; _Pred = std::equal_to<QString>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> > >]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  141 |       unordered_map() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:141:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_Hashtable() [with _Key = QString; _Value = std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<QString>; _H1 = std::hash<QString>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:414:7: note: ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::_Hashtable() [with _Key = QString; _Value = std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<QString>; _H1 = std::hash<QString>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> ’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  414 |       _Hashtable() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:414:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _Traits>::_Hashtable_base() [with _Key = QString; _Value = std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<QString>; _H1 = std::hash<QString>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1822:5: note: ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _Traits>::_Hashtable_base() [with _Key = QString; _Value = std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<QString>; _H1 = std::hash<QString>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 1822 |     _Hashtable_base() = default;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1822:5: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_Hash_code_base() [with _Key = QString; _Value = std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _H1 = std::hash<QString>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1373:7: note: ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_Hash_code_base() [with _Key = QString; _Value = std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _H1 = std::hash<QString>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 1373 |       _Hash_code_base() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1373:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper<_Nm, _Tp, true>::_Hashtable_ebo_helper() [with int _Nm = 1; _Tp = std::hash<QString>]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1096:7: note: ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper<_Nm, _Tp, true>::_Hashtable_ebo_helper() [with int _Nm = 1; _Tp = std::hash<QString>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 1096 |       _Hashtable_ebo_helper() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1096:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::hash<QString>::hash()’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string_view:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/array:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:54,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:101:12: note: ‘std::hash<QString>::hash()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  101 |     struct hash : __hash_enum<_Tp>
      |            ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:101:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__hash_enum<QString, false>::__hash_enum()’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:82:7: note: candidate: ‘std::__hash_enum<_Tp, <anonymous> >::__hash_enum(std::__hash_enum<_Tp, <anonymous> >&&) [with _Tp = QString; bool <anonymous> = false]’
   82 |       __hash_enum(__hash_enum&&);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:82:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:101:12: error: ‘std::__hash_enum<_Tp, <anonymous> >::~__hash_enum() [with _Tp = QString; bool <anonymous> = false]’ is private within this context
  101 |     struct hash : __hash_enum<_Tp>
      |            ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:83:7: note: declared private here
   83 |       ~__hash_enum();
      |       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1096:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::hash<QString>::~hash()’
 1096 |       _Hashtable_ebo_helper() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string_view:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/array:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:54,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:101:12: note: ‘std::hash<QString>::~hash()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  101 |     struct hash : __hash_enum<_Tp>
      |            ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:101:12: error: ‘std::__hash_enum<_Tp, <anonymous> >::~__hash_enum() [with _Tp = QString; bool <anonymous> = false]’ is private within this context
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:83:7: note: declared private here
   83 |       ~__hash_enum();
      |       ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1373:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, std::hash<QString>, true>::~_Hashtable_ebo_helper()’
 1373 |       _Hash_code_base() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1093:12: note: ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, std::hash<QString>, true>::~_Hashtable_ebo_helper()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 1093 |     struct _Hashtable_ebo_helper<_Nm, _Tp, true>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1093:12: error: use of deleted function ‘std::hash<QString>::~hash()’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1822:5: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<QString, std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash<QString>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::~_Hash_code_base()’
 1822 |     _Hashtable_base() = default;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1346:12: note: ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<QString, std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash<QString>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::~_Hash_code_base()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 1346 |     struct _Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1347 |       _Default_ranged_hash, true>
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1346:12: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, std::hash<QString>, true>::~_Hashtable_ebo_helper()’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:414:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<QString, std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<QString>, std::hash<QString>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::~_Hashtable_base()’
  414 |       _Hashtable() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1770:10: note: ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<QString, std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<QString>, std::hash<QString>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::~_Hashtable_base()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 1770 |   struct _Hashtable_base
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1770:10: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<QString, std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash<QString>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::~_Hash_code_base()’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/unordered_map:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:71,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/unordered_map_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/unordered_map-qstring/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Alloc, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, _Traits>::~_Hashtable() [with _Key = QString; _Value = std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> > >; _ExtractKey = std::__detail::_Select1st; _Equal = std::equal_to<QString>; _H1 = std::hash<QString>; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; _Traits = std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true>]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:102:11:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:1354:5: error: use of deleted function ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<QString, std::pair<const QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<QString>, std::hash<QString>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >::~_Hashtable_base()’
 1354 |     }
      |     ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/unique_ptr_qstring.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/unique_ptr_qstring.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/unique_ptr_qstring.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

### Example 3 (not working): QHash and QString

#### qhash_qstring.h

```cpp
#ifndef QHASH_QSTRING_H
#define QHASH_QSTRING_H

#include <QHash>
#include <QString>

#include <memory>

class QHashQString
{
public:
    QHashQString() {};

    QHash<QString, std::unique_ptr<QString>> container;

    void addItem(QString aKey, std::unique_ptr<QString> aValue);

    void showItem(QString aKey);
};

#endif // QHASH_QSTRING_H
```

#### qhash_qstring.cpp

```cpp
#include "qhash_qstring.h"

#include <iostream>

void QHashQString::addItem(QString aKey, std::unique_ptr<QString> aValue)
{
    container[aKey] = std::move(aValue);
}

void QHashQString::showItem(QString aKey)
{
    QString *aValue = container[aKey].get();
    std::cout << "Item '" << aKey.toStdString() << "': '" << (*aValue).toStdString() << "'\n";
}
```

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "qhash_qstring.h"

#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QHashQString testContainer;

    testContainer.addItem("key 1", std::make_unique<QString>("one value"));
    testContainer.addItem("key 2", std::make_unique<QString>("two value"));
    testContainer.addItem("key 3", std::make_unique<QString>("three value"));

    testContainer.showItem("key 2");
    testContainer.showItem("key 3");
    testContainer.showItem("key 2");

    return 0;
}
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(qhash_qstring LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_executable(qhash_qstring
  main.cpp
  qhash_qstring.h qhash_qstring.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(qhash_qstring Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)
```

#### Edit 3: compile errors for example 3

```
$ make
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qhash_qstring.dir/qhash_qstring.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QHash:1,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/qhash-qstring/qhash_qstring.h:4,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/qhash-qstring/qhash_qstring.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhash.h: In instantiation of ‘QHashNode<Key, T>::QHashNode(const Key&, const T&, uint, QHashNode<Key, T>*) [with Key = QString; T = std::unique_ptr<QString>; uint = unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhash.h:562:18:   required from ‘QHash<K, V>::Node* QHash<K, V>::createNode(uint, const Key&, const T&, QHash<K, V>::Node**) [with Key = QString; T = std::unique_ptr<QString>; QHash<K, V>::Node = QHashNode<QString, std::unique_ptr<QString> >; uint = unsigned int]’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhash.h:762:16:   required from ‘T& QHash<K, V>::operator[](const Key&) [with Key = QString; T = std::unique_ptr<QString>]’
/home/rodrigo/devel/qhash-qstring/qhash_qstring.cpp:7:19:   required from here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhash.h:157:52: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = QString; _Dp = std::default_delete<QString>]’
  157 |         : next(n), h(hash), key(key0), value(value0) {}
      |                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/memory:80,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/qhash-qstring/qhash_qstring.h:7,
                 from /home/rodrigo/devel/qhash-qstring/qhash_qstring.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:414:7: note: declared here
  414 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/qhash_qstring.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/qhash_qstring.dir/qhash_qstring.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/qhash_qstring.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Apart from the usecase to store a QString/std::string in a container as unique pointer - the second example works fine for me, the third can't work because QHash::insert() has no overload to take a rvalue reference.

Comment: @chehrlic I get `In constructor ‘UnorderedMapQString::UnorderedMapQString()’:`, `unordered_map_qstring.h:12:27: error: use of deleted function...` errors when compiling the second example. Do you have any idea what can I be doing wrong?

Comment: @chehrlic Is there a fix for the third example?

Comment: I am using QString/std::string inside the unique_ptrs just as a test/study case. My actual use will involve other classes.

Comment: A fix for the third is not possible until you add the function to QHash. Don't know why the second should not work for you. Simply use std::unordered_map() if you really need a unique_ptr.

Comment: What is the deleted function? As far as I remember, all Qt containers are implicitly shared and require their parameter types to be copyable, which unique_ptr is not.

Comment: @sigma I included the error messages for the 2 problematic examples on the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 2 does not compile because [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) requires its key type to be "hashable": by default, it will use the `std::hash` template. You can make it work by writing a specialisation for `QString`:

```
#include <functional>     // std::hash
#include <QHashFunctions> // qHash
#include <QString>

template<>
struct std::hash<QString>
{
    std::size_t operator()(QString const& s) const noexcept
    {
        return qHash(s);
    }
};
```

Example 3 does not compile because Qt containers use [implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) and only support copy semantics, even when inserting new elements. Therefore the compiler is looking for the copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr`, which is deleted:

```
unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

This example cannot be made to work, it's a fundamental design difference between Qt and standard library containers.

Comment: I had to include `<QHashFunctions>` and `<functional>`. Then it worked perfectly. Please consider mentioning these includes in your answer.